# Upgrading server/code to TLS 1.2, duplicate and reoccuring error in event log

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2, event-viewer

We upgraded our code and server in June to be PCI Compliant but now we are getting this error below in our event log all over the place.  Is there anyway to stop this without turning TLS 1.0 back on and not turning on FIPS?

> A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

Comment: for PCIDSS you can either disable SSL and TLS  1.0 for incoming communications only (Server key in schannel registry entry for each SSL and TLS) or you can block incoming and outgoing all together, in your case i am thinking the issue might be happeneing because your provider accepts an weak version of SSL or TLS or Cipher suites. you can ask the provider to upgrafe their security or you can enable TLS for outgoing communications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using IISCrypto and unchecking "client" when disabled TLS1.0, etc.  Those protocoals are enabled for the server, with requests going out, but disabled still for incoming requests to stay PCI compliant.

You can also disable this stuff manually in regedit, just for the client which a quick Google could do.